# Merge pandas groupBy objects

Tags: python, pandas, performance, bigdata, pandas-groupby

I have a huge dataset of 292 million rows (6GB) in CSV format. Panda's `read_csv` function is not working for such big file. So I am reading data in small chunks (10 million rows) iteratively using this code :

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('hugeData.csv', chunksize=10**7):
       #something ...
```

In the #something I am grouping rows according to some columns. So in each iteration, I get new groupBy objects. I am not able to merge these groupBy objects.

**A smaller dummy example is as follows :**

Here `dummy.csv` is a 28 rows CSV file, which is trade report between some countries in some year. *sitc* is some product code and *export* is export amount in some USD billion. (Please note that data is fictional)

```
year,origin,dest,sitc,export
2000,ind,chn,2146,2
2000,ind,chn,4132,7
2001,ind,chn,2146,3
2001,ind,chn,4132,10
2002,ind,chn,2227,7
2002,ind,chn,4132,7
2000,ind,aus,7777,19
2001,ind,aus,2146,30
2001,ind,aus,4132,12
2002,ind,aus,4133,30
2000,aus,ind,4132,6
2001,aus,ind,2146,8
2001,chn,aus,1777,9
2001,chn,aus,1977,31
2001,chn,aus,1754,12
2002,chn,aus,8987,7
2001,chn,aus,4879,3
2002,aus,chn,3489,7
2002,chn,aus,2092,30
2002,chn,aus,4133,13
2002,aus,ind,0193,6
2002,aus,ind,0289,8
2003,chn,aus,0839,9
2003,chn,aus,9867,31
2003,aus,chn,3442,3
2004,aus,chn,3344,17
2005,aus,chn,3489,11
2001,aus,ind,0893,17
```

I split it into two 14 rows data and grouped them according to year, origin, dest.

```
 for chunk in pd.read_csv('dummy.csv', chunksize=14):
       xd = chunk.groupby(['origin','dest','year'])['export'].sum();
       print(xd)
```

**Results :**

```
origin  dest  year
aus     ind   2000     6
              2001     8
chn     aus   2001    40
ind     aus   2000    19
              2001    42
              2002    30
        chn   2000     9
              2001    13
              2002    14
Name: export, dtype: int64
origin  dest  year
aus     chn   2002     7
              2003     3
              2004    17
              2005    11
        ind   2001    17
              2002    14
chn     aus   2001    15
              2002    50
              2003    40
Name: export, dtype: int64
```

**How can I merge the two GroupBy objects?**

Will merging them, again create memory issues in the big data? A prediction by looking at the nature of data, if properly merged the number of rows will surely reduce by at least 10-15 times.

**The basic aim is :**

Given origin country and dest country, 
I need to plot total exports between them yearwise. 
Querying this everytime over the whole data is taking a lot of time.

```
xd = chunk.loc[(chunk.origin == country1) & (chunk.dest == country2)]
```

Hence I was thinking to save time by once arranging them in groupBy manner.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For **origin** : aus and **dest** : ind, Merged data should be : { 2000 : 6, 2001 : 25, 2002 : 14 }

Comment: Two groupby objects are just dataframe slices, you can merge them with standard tools like `pd.concat`, `pd.merge`, `pd.join`.

Comment: I stored first split in xd0 and second split in xd1 and applied `pd.merge(xd0,xd1,on="origin")`.
I am getting error :
`ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: This is working : `pd.concat([xd0,xd1], axis=1)`. But it creates two different column of export.
[aus ind 2000 6.0 NaN],
[aus ind 2001 8.0 17.0],
[aus ind 2002 NaN 14.0]

Comment: Could you show the output that you need?

Comment: @hellpanderr : Sir I updated my answer to make clear how the output should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to join groupby results and then apply `sum`:

```
>>> pd.concat([xd0,xd1],axis=1)
                  export  export
origin dest year                
aus    ind  2000       6       6
            2001       8       8
chn    aus  2001      40      40
ind    aus  2000      19      19
            2001      42      42
            2002      30      30
       chn  2000       9       9
            2001      13      13
            2002      14      14

>>> pd.concat([xd0,xd1],axis=1).sum(axis=1)
origin  dest  year
aus     ind   2000    12
              2001    16
chn     aus   2001    80
ind     aus   2000    38
              2001    84
              2002    60
        chn   2000    18
              2001    26
              2002    28
```

Comment: Sir @hellpanderr , the problem got solved. It is taking 9 min to merge and create a big simplified dictionary (1,000,816 rows). Further query execution takes neglible time (in ms) to output. Is there any way I can save the groupBy object in my local hard disk in the dictionary form. So that the next time when I start over again, I can directly load the data (obviously in less than 9 min) and output the queries.

Comment: Do you want to save the result of `pd.concat`? A huge Series?

Comment: Yes sir. The full huge series. The number of rows is 1million, so I hope it can be saved in some MBs, whose loading time will be very less. So that from next time, if just load('series.xyz') I get the Series data in few seconds.

Comment: Sir @hellpanderr, save as in I meant to write it in my hard disk, just as we do in `xd.to_csv('series.csv')`.

Comment: What do you mean by dictionary form? Like json?

Comment: I mean any form. So that when I load the file. I get back the series.

Comment: Sir I figured it out. `xd.to_pickle("./backup.pkl")` and then called back `xdBack = pd.read_pickle("./dummy.pkl")`.I would like to thank you a lot for your help.